# statistical test between groups with multiple categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

I have a data frame of 58 categorical variables (0, 1 and 2) with 100 respondents from 4 different groups. I want to understand the statistical difference between the groups in terms of the variables categories (including all 58 variables, if possible)and their levels. Small theoretical example below:

Respondents respondent_groups Variable1 Variable2.........Variable58

1                  A                 0          1                 2

2               B                 2          2                 0

Could someone give few pointers about tests which I can do? 
Thank you